# Can promises execute out of order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
const someAsyncFunc = async (num) => {
  console.log(num);
}

someAsyncFunc(123);
someAsyncFunc(234);
```

Is it theoretically possible that 234 will be printed first? In general, if I invoke one async function before another, is it guaranteed that the first function will begin executing before the second one begins executing? Do I have to assume that any promise may be delayed indefinitely before it starts executing, or is there some guarantee on when it starts executing?

Comment: great video on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lum0R6Ng6R8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. Actually `async` functions execute synchronously till the first `await`. It gets more interesting if we add an `await`:

```
  const someAsyncFunc = async (num) => {
   console.log(`before ${num}`);
   await Promise.resolve();
   console.log(`after ${num}`);
  };

  someAsyncFunc(1);
  someAsyncFunc(2);
```

Now that will produce "before 1, before 2, after 1, after2". That order will never change, because the task to continue execution of the function gets enqueued into a task queue (synchronously, as the Promise resolves immeadiately) and therefore the order is guaranteed too.

Now if you `await` two Promises that will resolve at different times in the future, then the order might differ.